# Adding Comment to a Cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, comments, ms-office, office365

Here is the tiny macro which is giving me the error:

Error: `Application Defined or Object Defined Error`

Here is the full code as per MatMug's suggestion:

```
Sub insertTodayDate()
    Dim cellD3 As Range
    Dim helpComment As String    
    Set cellD3 = Range("D3")
    cellD3.FormulaR1C1 = "=Today()"
    cellD3.Copy
    cellD3.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    cellD3.Select
    helpComment = "hello"
    Call addCustomComment(helpComment)
    Range("D4").Select
End Sub

Sub addCustomComment(text)
    Dim wksProforma As Worksheet
    Dim dateRange As Range
    Set wksProforma = Worksheets("Proforma")
    Set dateRange = wksProforma.Range("D3")
    dateRange.AddComment "text"
End Sub
```

Why is the last line `dateRange.AddComment(text)` not working?

Thanks

Comment: I changed that for testing but it doesnt work if I do `dateRange.AddComment(text)`

Comment: No repro here, with or without the unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: Are you expecting a comment containing *text*? If so use `dateRange.AddComment "text"`. If not, declare and assign a string of text to a variable called **text** before using it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks, could it be due to Excel 2007 bug? I doubt it.

Comment: @Jeeped text is a parameter I pass to this function from another function. It doesnt work even if I change it to simple "text"

Comment: At this point I think it would be beneficial to [edit] your *actual* code into the question, or a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Still no repro, the code works fine (Excel 2010 32-bit, running on Win7 x64)

Comment: @Mat'sMug thank you for the effort. Definitely not working in Excel 2007 here at work :!

Comment: Are you trying to add a comment to a cell which already has one?  You cannot do that with your current line.